# convert data to json(jquery select2 plugin)

Tags: php, json

I have a table **users**. in this table i have a field and in that field data is something like this **test,test1,test2**. 
I am using ajax to fetch the data from this table and show it on php file.

I am able to fetch the data but due to select2 plugin. i need to make proper formatting of this data.

**fetch.php**

```
   $data = array();
    while ($result->fetch()) {
    $data['title'] = $title;
    $data['opening'] = $opening;
    $data['description'] = $description;
    $data['keywords'] = $keywords;
}
 echo json_encode($data);
```

keywords field have data something like this `test,test1,test2`

i need to make it in proper json format like this.

```
id:test text:test
id:test1 text:test1
```

so on.

Is it possible to make it like.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php Also your exmaple output is not valid JSON

Comment: i am using json encode but problem with keywords data.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [Minimum Complete Verifiable Code Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i think i have given all the necessary information.   $data['title'] = $title;
    $data['opening'] = $opening; is returning fine but keywords return like test,test1,test2

Comment: keyword is test understood. Where is text? As per your required output?

Comment: I appreciate your efforts and its been hard for you to understand the situation.

Comment: then just explode the keywords to an array with the proper format. Could you post an exampe of $keywords?

Comment: This wouldn't be an issue if your data was normalized and relational like it should be.  Storing multiple values in a single field makes all of those values into one single string.  The code converts that string to a single JSON string as expected.

Comment: its already given there Kordi

Comment: from where `text:test` is coming in your expected outcome? also your expected outcome is not valid `JSON`

Comment: i have to make it like this. its not coming from anyware.

Comment: so your id and text both will have keyword from while?

Comment: Thanks Anant. I will check and let you know. Till the time you can paste that in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code in your code (new code have comment):-

```
<?php
    $data = array();
    while ($result->fetch()) {
        $data['title'] = $title;
        $data['opening'] = $opening;
        $data['description'] = $description;
        $data['keywords'] = $keywords;
    }
    // code need to add
    $new_data = explode(',',$data['keywords']);
    $final_data = array();
    foreach($new_data as $new_dat){
        $final_data[] = array('id'=>$new_dat,'text'=>$new_dat);
    }
    echo "<pre/>";print_r( $final_data);
    $data['keywords'] = $final_data; // assingnment
   // print json encoded data in last
    echo json_encode($data);
 ?>
```

An example code:-  https://eval.in/528365

Comment: Anant I can say you are the best. This is what i was looking. There are lots of down vote to this question. But you made my day. Thanks a ton.

Comment: ha ha. I just guess what you want and i have to say i am fortunate enough. glad to help you. thanks.

Comment: Its already voted up and answer accepted. This question will help many people. Those are planning to use jquery select2 plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can make and two dimensional array inside empty array and $arrays = ('a' => 'b') like this then json_encode($arrays)  now you get json object

Comment: thanks for your answer. i have updated the question. Actually i am using json encode but i want to make proper format for keywords data.

Comment: i gave u an answer ?

Comment: please elaborate. I am not that much of intelligent.

Comment: you can do something like $a = array($key => $value,$key => $value,$key => $value,$key => $value,$key => $value); then json encode or else you can merge the array from loop what ever suits you

Answer (score 1):

Is this what are you looking for:

```
    while ($result->fetch()) {
    $data['title'] = $title;
    $data['opening'] = $opening;
    $data['description'] = $description;
    $data['keywords'] = $keywords;

    $data = array(
          "id" => $data['keywords'],
          "text" => $data['keywords']
    );
}
 echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will give it a try. one question i have. you didn't defined what contain "id" => $data['keywords'],
          "text" => $data['keywords'] this. Suppose if i use it in ajax then what do i need to call. for title its title.

Comment: Sorry I did not understand your question

Comment: also this solution is as per what I have understood your requirement. Because @Anant has interpreted your requirement in very different way.

Comment: Thanks Fakhurddin. Your solution is also working for me. Voted up.

Comment: Glad to help you :). No one spells my name properly :(

Comment: Indian can spells.  :)

Comment: we proud to be an indian @FakhruddinUjjainwala